# Avoid group of revisions history view duplication

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

My taxonomy View lists all revisions grouping by different columns, by adding revision fields for each value, and get the filter "published" removed.
The only filter is: city name (not null).

For example:

| London      | Roma       |

| value 1    | value 1            |

| value 2   | value 2           |

As you can tell, people can add different city data by making new revision of the taxonomy.
It works perfect, except one thing - If people want to revise an existed City, he will need to make a new revision, which will duplicate the city name on my View (resulting two columns of a same city).

Is there any way we can hide the elder column if city name duplicates?
I just want to keep "London & Roma", not "London & Roma & London"

There is no luck with Views Distinct & Views Field Compare, those two modules won't help.
Same with built-in Aggression.

Thanks. Drupal 8.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the view to Grid layout, grouping by City, so that I can hide every views-col in each group except the last one, by css control:

```
.views-view-grid .views-row .views-col {
display:none;
}
.views-view-grid .views-row .views-col:last-child {
display:inline-block !important;
}
```

It works. But wondering if there is any other way.